# Can the Light cantrip create effective darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, cantrips

The *Light* cantrip allows for adjustments in the color of the light it produces.

> You touch one object that is no larger than 10 feet in any dimension. Until the spell ends, the object sheds bright light in a 20-foot radius and dim light for an additional 20 feet. **The light can be colored as you like.** Completely covering the object with something opaque blocks the light...

[Black is a color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black). In fact, there are different [shades of black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_black). If I choose black as the intended color while casting this cantrip, would I be creating an area of magical darkness?

Comment: Our old physics teacher used to get all pedantic on us and remind us that black wasn't technically a color, but an absence of light. Not sure if they still teach that.

Comment: Light uses an additive model of colour, unlike pigments which use subtractive model, you can't add light to make something darker. http://learn.leighcotnoir.com/artspeak/elements-color/primary-colors/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There's no such thing as gray light.

You can't make a light source that's nearly black or even just gray, but to explain why I need to go into a little detail about how colors work.

There are a lot of ways to define the term 'color'. The most useful one in this context is, I feel, the HSL system, or "hue, saturation, luminance". Without going into excessive detail, you can define (nearly) any color in terms of three values:

Hue defines where on the spectrum you are, from pure red to pure violet.

Saturation describes how pure or grayish the color is, from fully saturated (a pure hue made up of a single frequency of light -- or a couple frequencies, because purples are weird) all the way down to a pale color that's very nearly white/gray/black (mixing in all the other frequencies of light in equal amounts, so your eye sees all the colors together -- that is, white -- plus a little extra of one color).

Luminance describes where you are on that range from black to white. Decreasing luminance makes the color darker overall and increasing it makes it brighter.

So for example, if you pick 'red' as your hue, a high saturation and high luminance is your pure red, #FF0000. But you can have a low saturation and high luminance to talk about pale pastel pink, or a high saturation and low luminance to talk about a deep red so dark it's nearly black. Because of the way eyes work, when you get very dark (low luminance) colors, it's hard to see small differences in saturation or hue, which a lot of video compression algorithms take advantage of.

Now, in reflected light, there's a legitimate meaning to the words 'white' and 'black' -- absolute white absorbs nothing, reflecting 100% of all the light that falls on it, while absolute black absorbs everything, reflecting nothing back. Grays fall between the two, absorbing some of the light and reflecting the rest. But when you're talking about a light *source* such as a TV screen, 'white', 'gray', and 'black' are relative terms. In all three cases, you're seeing equal amounts of light in all the colors, and we're just making an arbitrary declaration of what "full luminance" and "no luminance" will mean in the context. For example, a black area on a TV or computer screen is often not very black at all, but dark gray. If you have a TV showing "black" in a darkened room, you can see that there's still quite a bit of light coming from the screen. We see black and gray in an image only by comparison to lighter areas of the screen. (Brown is the same, for that matter. It's actually "dark orange" if you look at it without the context of surrounding objects, and that's why you can't make a brown light.)

In any case, you can't actually have a gray light source, because turning down the luminance just means making the light *dimmer*. We sometimes talk about light being grayish, but that's by way of comparison to the normal intensity -- the light under a storm cloud or through a dirty window is just less bright than clear sunlight, and often a little less reddish, but not actually 'gray' by any universal standard.

So bringing it back to the *light* spell: If the light it's shedding is fixed to a specific brightness (a bit brighter than a torch, about the same as a good lantern), then you can't really touch luminance. You can change the hue and saturation as much as you like to make a pure white light, a pale pink light, or a vivid violet light, but you can't make your light gray or black without doing something the spell doesn't let you do. If you turned the luminance down, you'd just be casting less light on the environment rather than producing light that is itself gray.

Now, yes, this is magic, and we could posit that there's some aspect of magical light that allows you to make it "dimmer" while still filling the space just as completely, but since *light* is specifically making an object glow, I think we have to interpret that you're dealing with normal light emitted by an object, and not just suffusing an area with sourceless radiance.

Answer (score 6):

#### Darkness is by definition the absence of light.

Unfortunately, a spell called *light* cannot create darkness. From the description:

> Until the spell ends, the object sheds bright light.

No reasonable reading of this statement can say “this spell creates darkness”.  Further, allowing *light* to produce darkness more or less emulates the effect of the 2nd level spell *darkness*.

I can briefly comment on the color bit. From the Wikipedia article you linked:

> These colors have a low lightness. From photometric point of view, a color which differs slightly from black always has low relative luminance.

These different shades of black are attributed to slight variations in how they absorb light. The “color” black absorbs light. The cantrip *light* creates “bright light”, so “low light” and “low relative luminance” are the opposite of what the spell produces.

Notably, black is not on the [color spectrum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_color), rather it is an absence of light on that spectrum, so even calling black a color is something of a category error.

Even lights commonly referred to as “black lights” [are purple](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklight).

#### There is room for flavor.

If I’m running the game, and you say “I create black light with the *light* spell”, I will say “go for it”. Narratively, you will create black light. Mechanically, it will be treated as exactly what the spell says - bright light. I’ll let you flavor it however you want. Mechanically it’s bright light, not darkness.

Comment: Take a Light spell colored with Blacklight into a temple to Graz'zt and it would look like a Jackson Pollock.

Comment: What if I chose the _Licorice_ (#1A1110) color (it's a shade of black) instead of pure black (#000000)? That's a color. And the cantrip says I can choose any color I like.

Comment: Ask your DM. In every campaign I’ve ever participated, hexadecimal color codes didn't exist.

Comment: Regarding the Blacklight bit mention, "Blacklight" refers to UV spectrum light, which can't be seen by human eyes and don't come in to sensory idea's of colour. (What you see under blacklight is due to fluorescence and is maybe more analogous to *faerie fire*)

Comment: @Someone_Evil Right, but the bulbs themselves are still visibly purple.

Comment: Thanks, @Someone_Evil, now every time someone casts *faerie fire* i'm going to just imagine they're casting *dorm room*.

Comment: @NautArch That's two of us, keep the meme going. 

Comment: More to the point of creating magical darkness; there is a spell explicitly for that (*darkness*) which is 2nd level, and typically you would not expect a cantrip to be able to (pretty much) fully emulate a higher level spell.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Your argument is the most convincing. Thank you everyone else for your inputs as well. :)

Comment: My character is going to start carrying a blacklight Elvis poster.